# Count number of consonants in a string

Tags: c, string, indexof

Another starter question.

```
int counterConstant;
int x;


for(x = 0; x<20; x++){
if("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSVWXYZ".IndexOf(tempString[x]) >= 0){
 counterConsonant++;
 }
}
```

But I get an error:

```
"error: member reference base type 'char [42]' is not a structure or union"
```

Is there another way I could do this?
(I'm doing this inside a `for` that checks each `char` on the `string`.)

Comment: Where did you find `IndexOf` in C? And do not use a magic number like 20 but `strlen(tempString)` instead

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc
I forced the stringLength to be 20 (I didn't declare it in my code up here but on my code its tempString[20];

Comment: Even in that case you should declare/define a constant. Magic number is dangerous

Comment: Even if you declare the array to be size 20, if you don't write to all of the characters than same can remain uninitialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no objects in C, so there are no "methods" and you can't call `IndexOf` on a string literal.  A string is nothing more than an array of characters in C.

With that in mind, let's see how you can actually loop over the characters of a string:

```
for (const char *p = tempString; *p != '\0'; ++p) {
    /* loop body */
    char c = *p; // *p is the current letter
}
```

This will create a pointer to the first element of the string, and then loop over all of the following characters, if you'd really prefer to use indexes, you could do

```
for (size_t i = 0, len = strlen(tempString); i < len; ++i) {
    char c = tempString[i];
}
```

As far as checking each letter for consonant-ness, that you can write a helper function for

```
int is_consonant(char c) {
    c = tolower(c); // #include <ctype.h>
    if (!isalpha(c)) return 0; // if not a letter, return false
    switch (c) {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
            return 0;
        default:
            return 1;
    }
}
```

now back to your loop, use this function to check each character.

```
int consonant_count = 0; // the =0 is important!
for (const char *p = tempString; *p != '\0'; ++p) {
    if (is_consonant(*p)) {
        ++consonant_count;
    }
}
```

If you don't initialize to 0, the initial value of `consonant_count` is unpredictable, so make sure you do.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation...and yes I confused c# function in c haha.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on C (as it was specified in tags), `strchr()` method is used to search a char in a string, and `strstr()` is used to search a string in a string. We will use `strchr()` here because `tempString[x]` is a char. Also, don't forget to give your `int` variable an initial value. Try this code:

```
int main()
{
    int counterConsonant = 0;
    int x;
    const char* tempString = "12345678901234567890";

    for (x = 0; x<20; x++){
        if (strchr("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSVWXYZ", tempString[x]) != NULL){
            counterConsonant++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char temp[20];
scanf("%s",temp);
int i,j, consonantsCounter=0;
char consonants[]={'b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z','B','C','D','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','V','W','X','Y','Z'}
for(i=0;i<20;i++){
  for(j=0;j<(sizeof consonants) / (sizeof consonants[0]);j++){
   if(temp[i]==consonants[j]){
      consonantsCounter++;
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: your array of `consonants` doesn't have any single quotes.  If you have an array written out, don't put the size just use `[]` and the compiler will figure out the size for you.  you're missing two closing braces.  `scanf` with `"%s"` is dangerous, use `fgets` instead.

Comment: @Ryan Haining Sorry I edited my answer, I missed them. But the array size can stay. I know compiler handle it

Comment: You're missing a closing quote after your `'G`.  You're better off letting the compiler figure it out because it will reduce errors by a great deal.  For example, you have entered a size of `[21]` but your array actually has 41 elements.  If you used empty brackets instead, you couldn't have this problem.  If you later change the contents of the array for some reason, you don't have to also update the size.  There is no real advantage to writing it out unless you want the size to be bigger than the number of initializers.  It's a bad habit and leads to the exact problem you have.

Comment: if you want the size of the array you can use `size_t sz = (sizeof consonants) / (sizeof consonants[0]);`

Comment: Yep I know that, I did mistake because I wrote this answer at late night. And also syntax error can easily fix from asker. Anyway thanks for concern

Comment: It's an extremely common mistake which is why you're better off letting the compiler do it for you, it's not a syntax error.  it *is* poor style though, I've seen it negatively affect projects.  Is there a reason you want to keep the size there?

Comment: @Ryan Haining Are you happy now? :)

Comment: certainly better, but you still have other problems.  If the user enters a string longer than 19 characters, then it will overrun the buffer, that's why scanf is unsafe to use in this case.  If it's shorter than 19 characters than the rest of the array will be uninitialized, and your inner loop will be checking against seemingly random values.

Comment: yep I know, I said that before but seems you didn't read. I wrote simple code, I do not have to full code that don't have bugs. I just wanted to give the idea about comparision. Otherwise you are right, we are on the same page.

Comment: I don't see your mention of it. Relying on what seems to be unlikely behavior isn't "simple" it's just wrong.  Since OP didn't mention where `tempString` comes from I'm a bit confused why you would assume it comes from stdin, and even so, why show an incorrect way to read a string from stdin if you know it's incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

C is a structured procedural language, so it doesn't have member functions/methods like a "true" object-oriented programming language such as C#.  You could use a combination of `strspn` and `strcspn` like below to count sequences of consonants and non-consonant characters respectively, based on a predefined list of consonant characters:

```
#include <string.h>

size_t
count_consonants (const char *s)
{
  size_t n;
  size_t total = 0;
  const char *consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";

  /* While we haven't reached the end of the string,
     execute the code in the body of the loop.  */
  while (*s != '\0')
    {
      /* Count the number of consonants starting at the current string position.  */
      n = strspn (s, consonants);

      /* Add the number of consonants counted to
         the total number of consonants found.  */
      total += n;

      /* Advance the character pointer to the next character
         that IS NOT a consonant, based on the number of consonants
         stored in `n'.  */
      s += n;

      /* Advance the character pointer to the next character
         that IS a consonant (`strcspn' = skip the characters in
         `s' that don't appear in `consonants').  */
      s += strcspn (s, consonants);
    }

  return total;
}
```